# How can I get the items all fixed in each position using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all the buttons to be fixed in certain positions, such as in each `<div>` item. Right now, the button location depends on the length of the texts above, but I want them to locate in the same position independently of the text length. For example, this is how my buttons look like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And I'd like to make them:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And I tried using fixed and absolute positioning for buttons, but all buttons were folded together in one position, which then I had to create separate CSS for individual buttons. Is there a simple way to adjust the button in the same position within the `<div>` item? Below is my code:

```css
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
}

.flexContainer > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.secondContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

li.title {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

li.author {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.isbn {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.flexItem {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;  //* Added *//
}

.flexItem img{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
}

button {
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.buttonCart {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonCart:hover {
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    color: white;
}

.buttonOnline {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonOnline:hover {
    background-color: #dd1d5e;
    color: white;
}

.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 140px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section>

<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="secondContainer">
      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/royal_ester.png" alt="Royal Easter" class="image">
                  <ul>
                      <li class="title"> The Royal Easter </li>
                      <li class="author"> Marshella Goodsworth </li>
                      <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                      <li class="price"> $14.99 </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="buttons">
                  <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
                  </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/easter_throughout_europe.png" alt="Easter Europe" class="image">
              <ul>
                  <li class="title"> Easter Throughout Europe </li>
                  <li class="author"> Nancy Silverman </li>
                  <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                  <li class="price"> $10.28 </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/southern_living.png" alt="Southern Living" class="image">
              <ul>
                  <li class="title"> Southern Living: Our Best Christmas </li>
                  <li class="author"> Jean Wickstrom Liles </li>
                  <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                  <li class="price"> $0.99 </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
              <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/thanksgiving_recipes.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
              <ul>
                  <li class="title"> Thanksgiving Recipes </li>
                  <li class="author"> Hannie P Scott </li>
                  <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                  <li class="price"> $2.92 </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
              <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
              <ul>
                  <li class="title"> Giving Thanks </li>
                  <li class="author"> Kathleen Curtin </li>
                  <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                  <li class="price"> $1.45 </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
              <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
              </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
          <img src="images/books/holiday/new_york_christmas.png" alt="New York Christmas" class="image">
              <ul>
                  <li class="title"> New York Christmas </li>
                  <li class="author"> Lisa Nieschlag </li>
                  <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
                  <li class="price"> $2.91 </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

++ so I changed to absolute position relative to the flexbox. However, it still shows it's not in the same position to the text and images.

Comment: use `postion: relative` on its parent and then `position: absolute` on the button and tell it with top/bottom and left/right where exactly you want it to be. It always will remain then at that position. you can also use a wrapper for the button and use the wrappe with a position absolute. That way you solve the issue if you use more then one button.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the input, what is tis aprent? When I used the ```position: absolute``` the buttons stayed in the exact position when I scroll the page up and down...

Comment: @sarahkim Right, using `position: absolute` on an element not in a container with `position: relative` be taken out of the document flow. However, if you set `position: relative` for each parent `<div id="text">`, then however you style the child buttons with `position: absolute` using top/bottom and left/right will be relative to the div and not the entire document.

Comment: @HelloWorld Thank you! I think I understand! I'm trying it now.

Comment: @HelloWorld So, I tried the ```position: absolute``` and it did work, but somehow they are not in the same position as the images and texts. Although I have all same styles applied. The images are exactly the same size also. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @sarahkim Hmm, do you mean that the images and texts have now changed position? Or the buttons aren't where you want them to be? I assume that now all the buttons are in the exact same place in each box, but maybe not in the right place?

Comment: @HelloWorld I attached a new picture, so they are not in the same location..... But when I run the code snippet, it looks like they are in same position? (weird).

Comment: @sarahkim That is strange. well, now at least they're in the same vertical position/alignment! It's now the reverse problem.  I see you're using `flex` in the `flexItem` and  `.text` classes; maybe by changing the flex properties, we'll get a better result. I'll try write up an actual answer at this point.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, I just removed ```.text``` class actually. I don't think it's needed. ```flexItem``` is doing all the work i guess. I just edited the code, and when I run the code snippet it shows they are in the same vertical line but not horizontal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223116/discussion-between-hello-world-and-sarah-kim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, the problem was solved: using `position: absolute` on an element not in a container with `position: relative` will take the element out of the document flow. However, if `position: relative` is set for each parent `<div id="text">`, then however you style `.buttons` with `position: absolute` using top/bottom and left/right will be relative to the div and not the entire document.

The `.text` class was also adding unnecessary flex constraints to the elements it contained.

This fixed the vertical inconsistencies:

```
.flexItem {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative; 
}
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 140px;
    top: 150px;
}
```

and horizontal consistency was achieved by adding `right`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `margin-top` property with a negative value to move the buttons up.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.flexContainer>div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.secondContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

li.title {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

li.author {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.isbn {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.flexItem img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

button {
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.buttonCart {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
  margin-top: -25px;           /* Makes the buttons move up */
}

.buttonCart:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}

.buttonOnline {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #dd1d5e;
}

.buttonOnline:hover {
  background-color: #dd1d5e;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="secondContainer">
      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/royal_ester.png" alt="Royal Easter" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> The Royal Easter </li>
            <li class="author"> Marshella Goodsworth </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $14.99 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/easter_throughout_europe.png" alt="Easter Europe" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> Easter Throughout Europe </li>
            <li class="author"> Nancy Silverman </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $10.28 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/southern_living.png" alt="Southern Living" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> Southern Living: Our Best Christmas </li>
            <li class="author"> Jean Wickstrom Liles </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $0.99 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
          <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/thanksgiving_recipes.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> Thanksgiving Recipes </li>
            <li class="author"> Hannie P Scott </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $2.92 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
          <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/giving_thanks.png" alt="Thanksgiving Recipes" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> Giving Thanks </li>
            <li class="author"> Kathleen Curtin </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $1.45 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
          <button class="button buttonOnline">Read Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexItem">
        <img src="images/books/holiday/new_york_christmas.png" alt="New York Christmas" class="image">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"> New York Christmas </li>
            <li class="author"> Lisa Nieschlag </li>
            <li class="isbn"> ISBN123123412 </li>
            <li class="price"> $2.91 </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="button buttonCart">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```